# What is the best way to have jquery work for elements added by ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, dom

EDIT :

I have a form with bootstrap datepicker plugin in a bootstrap model :

Initiate the plugin :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    // datepicker plugin
    $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
         // options
    });
});
</script>
```

added at footer in a custom.js file and the form input :

```
<div class="input-group date">
     <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" required><span lass="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

This works good without no problems.

Now if i add the exact same model content from a file with GET method the plugin for the datepicker dosen’t work any more. I have to add to the file send to the model :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        // datepicker plugin
        $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
             // options
        });
    });
</script>
```

for it to work again. 
Now my question is : What is the best way to fix the problem?

Comment: If you are going to downgrade my question at least tell what is bad about  it. Thanks.

Comment: better if you check your text for grammatical errors. Please also don't write the same code twice. For the next time I suggest you to take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking a few days for a better way to fix my problem I found out that I had the correct answer.